# firebase_messaging callbacks don't fire when in foreground . iOS app Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm porting my Swift app to Flutter and I'm setting up the FCM using `firebase_messaging`package.
When using my Swift app if I send a test message from Firebase console either directly to token or broadly, and I get the notification delivered to the system tray whether the app is in foreground or in background.

This doesn't happen with the Flutter app. 
When App is in background I still get both notification in the system tray, but when in foreground none of the `onMessage`, `onLaunch` or `onResume` callbacks gets called.

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks.

```
class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  String _token;
  String _launchMessage;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));

    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on message $message');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on resume $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on launch $message');
      },
    );

    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print('token: $token');
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _token = token;
        });
      } else {
        _token = token;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem being the package itself. When switching to MaikuB fork of the plugin it all works as expected.

```
#  firebase_messaging: 6.0.9 # doesn't work

      firebase_messaging: # works properly
        git:
          url: https://github.com/MaikuB/flutterfire.git
          path: packages/firebase_messaging
```

He told me that this is been merged to the official repo so it's due an update of the plugin that saves this. MaikuB's fork actually solves incompatibility with other plugins that need to register to

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
```

as  his own `flutter_local_notification`plugin , used to show local notification.

I hope that this can help other while a new version of the plugin is rolled out, as making it work has been quite frustrating..

Cheers